# A Protein-Based Riddle In Multiple Parts

Tags: riddle, word

Let x be the answer.

Given that x is:

1. Associated with a baroque painter and an ungulate
2. A possibility to be faced by half of us
3. Similar in sound to having been served a beverage

And the following equation holds true:

> (x - DROPLET) + (x - MINSTREL) + (x - CANIFORM_CREATURE) = RAINBOW_EDGE

Solve for x and explain the clues.

Comment: rainbow edge could be red or violet?

Comment: A possibility facing half of us could be something that only men or only women experience. Could it be childbirth? Or period?

Comment: @Richard Roe: Or color blindness. Or endometrial cancer. Or menopause.

Comment: @Gamow On the other hand, this could be a cryptic crossword style clue, meaning half of the word "us" that is, "u" or "s". I don't see how this would work, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

x is:

> BEARD

1. Associated with a baroque painter and an ungulate

   > A Van Dyke and a goatee
   >  *(thanks to Wikipedia for the first one)*
2. A possibility to be faced by half of us

   > Only men can possibly have one
3. Similar in sound to having been served a beverage

   > "BEER-ED" *(is there really such a word?)*

Equation:

> (BEARD - BEAD) + (BEARD - BARD) + (BEARD - BEAR) = R + E + D = RED

Title:

> Beard is made of hair which is a protein filament
>  *(thanks to @Hugh for the link)*

Credit to @manshu for steering me towards anagrams.

Comment: For the first half of clue 1, I would guess: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Dyke_beard

Comment: You want the bearded pig (sus babyrus) for clue 1

Comment: @Gamow: Just found that on Wikipedia a few minutes ago.  ;)

Comment: Guess what it's made of? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair

Comment: I was looking for a way to work in "bread" as an anagram but I couldn't come up with anything clever.

Comment: I know some women who can grow beards, and some men who can't

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: Very well, then that's still "half of us"!  :)

Comment: wasn't arguing,  just stating (Plus if I know 3 women who can grow beards, and 2 men that can't, that isn't half)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: But _I_ know the 3rd man.  :)  Don't worry, I'm not arguing either, just kidding around...

Comment: Also, there are only 100 females for every 101 males, so that's clearly not half of the human population!

Comment: @ffao But then I know a friend who don't have any beard but don't know any women with beard. :p

Comment: @ffao: What?! No wonder I'm still single...  BTW, an unverified, un-peer-reviewed, unrecorded study showed that almost exactly 0.49505% of all men lived in a social or work environment which required them not to have a beard _[citation needed]_, and thus it wasn't a possibility for them.

Comment: @HughMeyers - A chin which lacks a **beard** can be described as **bared**.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Did you circle the globe ardently looking for that anagram?

Comment: @KeyboardWielder re: *"BEER-ED" (is there really such a word?)* ... "Beer me!"

Comment: @feelinferrety I was thinking just that.